# Laravel 7- Undefined Offset error while fetching data from database

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to fetch data from database, but I am getting an error `Undefined Offset 8`. It seems like the data that I am trying to fetch is not available in database.

**But as `array_key_exists()` function with objects is deprecated in php 7.4, I am not sure how to check if an offset/ array key exists**

Here is my code :-

**Blade**

```
//Other codes

@for($i=0;$i<13; $i++)
    {{$modules[$i]}}
@endfor
```

**Controller**

```
public function index(){
   $data['modules'] = DB::select('users')->where('user_deleted_flag','!=',true)->get();
  return view('index', $data);
}
```

**Web.php**

```
Route::get('index', 'ViewController@index');
```

So, how do I check if offset value upto 13  or data exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take the minimum of the # of elements in the array and 13.

```
@for($i = 0; $i < min(count($modules), 13); $i++)
    {{ $modules[$i] }}
@endfor
```

Alternatively you could limit the resultset of the query on the backend to 13 if that would be something you'de like.
[DB: Query Builder Skip/Take](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset)

Comment: 13 is kind of a user defined number. If the user wants to see 13 data items, then s/he shall enter 13. If there aren't 13 data, then the loop should close before the last data. I used a constant just for a better understanding

Comment: @Skumar take a look at the loop

Answer (score 1):

You can use `isset`

```
@for($i=0;$i<13; $i++)
    @if(!isset($modules[$i]))
        @break
    @endif
    {{$modules[$i]}}
@endfor
```

Comment: It says isset() requires more variables

Comment: it's not a best way, you first run cycle and then do check, why ?
You should do check and only then run a cycle.It's more better for performance

Answer (score 1):

You can use if in blade

```
@if(count($modules)) 
 @for($i=0;$i<13; $i++)
 {{$modules[$i]}}
 @endfor
@endif
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use foreach in blade:

```
@foreach($modules as $key => $module)
{
  {{ $module[$key] }}
}
@endforeach
```

Comment: I am not allowed to use `foreach`, because of the complexity (there are a lot of things that I havent shown)